# Make edges thicker in NetworkX

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx, data-analysis

```
  student_id  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
0   131X1319  1  14   6  16   1  10   8  15  15  17  15  18  16
1   13212YX3  1   1   4   8  11   9  14   7   0   3   0  17  13
2   13216131  1   1  13   9  15  17   0   9   3  15  11   8  10
3   132921W6  1  14  10   4  18   7   8  15  15  17  15  18  16
```

I have a dataframe like this. And I want to make a graph using networkX. And I want to make the edge thicker each time an edge goes from one node to another node. Suppose,
`15->15->17->15->18->16`
appears twice in the dataframe. So, I want to increase the thickness to two. I made the normal graph but not been able to increase the graph thickness.
This is my code to create the normal graph:

```
columns=list(pattern_df.columns.values)
pattern_g = nx.empty_graph(0, nx.DiGraph())
for i in range(len(columns)-1):
     pattern_g.add_edges_from(zip(pattern_df[columns[i]], 
pattern_df[columns[i+1]]))
sum_val=pattern_df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=0)
values = [sum_val.get(node, 0.25) for node in pattern_g.nodes()]
nx.draw(pattern_g, with_labels=True, font_color='black')
plt.show()
```

This is the graph I have generated to the sample data:

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you mean the line thickness when you plot?

Comment: yes. I want to increase the thickness going from one node to another.

Comment: could you please fix the indentation of your posted code?

Comment: I'm sorry. fixed the indentations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done a poor job of explaining what you're trying to do. Also, it would have been nice if you had provided code that could work with a simple copy and paste.

I suspect that what you have in mind is something like this.

> And I want to make the edge thicker each time an edge goes from one node to another node. Suppose **that the sequence
> `15 15 17 15 18 16`**
> appears **in two different rows** in the dataframe. So, I want to increase the thickness **of each edge corresponding to a contiguous pair within that sequence, i.e. `15->15, 15->17, 17->15` and so forth**.

Your explanation doesn't say what should happen if the same pair appears multiple times within the same row; I assume that such repetitions should separately count towards the thickness of that edge.

Here is some code that **does** work if you simply copy and paste it and does my best guess at what you're trying to do (i.e. assumes my interpretation is correct).

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Reconstruct the dataframe from its inconvenient format
df_str = '''  student_id  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
0   131X1319  1  14   6  16   1  10   8  15  15  17  15  18  16
1   13212YX3  1   1   4   8  11   9  14   7   0   3   0  17  13
2   13216131  1   1  13   9  15  17   0   9   3  15  11   8  10
3   132921W6  1  14  10   4  18   7   8  15  15  17  15  18  16
'''
lines = df_str.splitlines()
cols = lines[0].split()
data = [line.split()[1:] for line in lines[1:]]
pattern_df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = cols)

# Count appearance of each edge
columns=list(pattern_df.columns.values)
ct = Counter(p for i in range(len(columns)-1) 
               for p in zip(pattern_df[columns[i]],pattern_df[columns[i+1]]))

# Build associated graph
pattern_g = nx.DiGraph()
pattern_g.add_edges_from(ct)

# Draw graph, using frequency of each pair as edge-width
width = [ct[p] for p in pattern_g.edges] 
nx.draw(pattern_g, node_color = 'orange', with_labels=True, width = width)
plt.show()
```

Here's the result.

[image]

---

Regarding your comment: in order to add the width of an edge as an attribute within the graph `pattern_g`, you can make the following change to the graph-building section of the script I suggested.

```
# Build associated graph
pattern_g = nx.DiGraph()
for e,v in ct.items():
    pattern_g.add_edge(*e, weight=v)
```

Comment: Hey. sorry for poorly posting the question. I am new to StackOverflow. But thanks for the suggestion. This is what I wanted to do. thanks again.

Comment: @blackstreetboy Sorry if I've come off as a bit hostile here; I'm glad to help. For future reference, a helpful way to make a dataframe directly usable by another user is to paste the result of `[DataFrame].head().to_dict()` into your question. With that, `pd.DataFrame(d)` (where d is the pasted dictionary) is a usable dataframe.

Comment: Hi.. I am getting a error 'AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'splitlines''

Comment: @blackstreetboy Another handy visualization technique is mapping values (in this case, the frequency of each pair) to a color within a gradient rather than mapping to line thickness. This can be done using the `edge_color` and `edge_cmap` arguments to `nx.draw`

Comment: @blackstreetboy That's strange. That shouldn't happen if you copy and pasted my code directly. For your purposes, you should be able to start from the `# Count appearance of each edge` section, as long as you include the `from collections import Counter` statement at the top

Comment: @BenGrossmann You get the data presented like this most of the times here on SO. Have a look at [`pd.read_clipboard`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html) which works fine here. Also [`pd.read_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html) with [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o) as buffer is possible (I use it for creating data from most of the questions)

Comment: @Rabinzel I didn’t know about the read_clipboard command, that’s fantastic! Thank you.

Comment: I want to add the width of each edge as the weight of that edge. how can I set the weight of each edge

Comment: @blackstreetboy I'm not sure what you think the benefit is of giving each edge an attribute within the graph `pattern_g` that you call its "weight". Perhaps you should explain what you're trying to accomplish with this change. It might be worth asking a new question; feel free a drop a link to that question here if you do.